# Filtering a large number of rows in Cassandra

Tags: query-performance, optimization, cassandra

Let's assume we have a lot of potentially heavy rows (e.g. 500k) in a table that we want to filter by primary keys and send over the internet to a processing engine.Is it reasonable to use the  `IN` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `IN` in Cassandra should be used very carefully. It's ok to use `IN` when you have a query against the same partition, but if query is against multiple partitions, then it's better to send individual requests - it will make less load onto the coordinating node, and also will be faster, as requests will be sent to nodes that hold the data (if you use Prepared queries with default token-aware load balancing)

Comment: Ok, but what if every partition key is unique, so there're distributed in a round robin fashion? Would sending 500k requests with a single primary key each one be more efficient than sending one request with 500k primary keys (would a DataStax driver allow to do such thing at all?).

Comment: Driver will allow it, but you need to be careful with number of parallel requests, etc.